# Internal Server Error after Heroku deploying with sql database

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, sequelize.js

I get a blank web page after deploying my node.js/express.js app with MYSQLdb to Heroku.

The app is working fine locally. I followed the guidelines to enable the JAWSDB add-on in Heroku and deployed it to Heroku without any problem. But when copying the link to run, the web page only shows "Internal Server Error". Could anyone help me to fix this problem?  The connection.js file is below:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
require('dotenv').config();

let sequelize;

if (process.env.JAWSDB_URL) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.JAWSDB_URL);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME,
    process.env.DB_USER,
    process.env.DB_PW,
    {
      host: 'localhost',
      dialect: 'mysql',
      port: 3306,
    },
  );
}
```

The server.js file is below:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./controllers');
const sequelize = require('./config/connection');
const helpers = require('./utils/helpers');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const hbs = exphbs.create({ helpers});
const session = require('express-session');
const SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);

const sess = {
  secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
  cookie: {
    // Stored in milliseconds (120 minutes)
    maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  },
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: new SequelizeStore({
    db: sequelize,
  }),
};

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(session(sess));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
app.use(routes);

sequelize.sync();

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

I have session/cookie setup for the app. Thank you.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I believe the above codes are necessary for others to understand how the app is configured for the Heroku deployment in which the problem occurred.